# Did something change with the way the Podcast files are hosted?

Tags: support, podcast

I am unable to download the last 2 episodes of the podcast on my phone.  Up to and including podcast 27, I had no problems downloading the podcasts.  Now for the last two episodes, I am unable to download the podcast.  It won't download in my podcast application, and it won't download directly from the browser either.  I'm using a Nokia Symbian phone if that is any help.  I don't think it's a problem with the phone, as all my other podcasts are downloading just fine.  Did something change in the way they are served?

**UPDATE**

It might have something to do with the tracking you are doing.  The original link in the feed is.

```
http://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/feeds.soundcloud.com/stream/29369082-stack-exchange-stack-exchange-podcast-29.mp3
```

If I take off the first part, for tracking and go straight to.

```
http://feeds.soundcloud.com/stream/29369082-stack-exchange-stack-exchange-podcast-29.mp3
```

It works just fine.

Was the www.podtrac.com part added recently?  Or has it always been used.  I'm pretty sure this is the part that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've been using podtrac since the relaunch of the podcast back in May, no changes there recently.  My guess would be a DNS issue with your provider since all Podtrac does is provide a redirect (and its working fine in all our tests).

Comment: You seem to be right.  I can't access the www.podtrac.com site at all from my phone.  Must be a problem with my provider.